# Where do I put my blueprint before_request

Tags: python, flask

So I have the before request routing for my user module. But now I want to access g.users from other blueprints as well. I found the only way to do it, is to copy the code below to every single blueprint.

I tried putting it in my app.py for @app.before_request, but then you have errors because you have to import session, g, User, and then still you get _requestglobal errors in other places.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
  g.user = None
  if 'user_id' in session:
    g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id']);
```

What's the best place to put it?

I get a lot of:

```
AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: `app.before_request` *should* work.  Can you post an example of a place where you would get the `AttributeError` when using `app.before_request`?

Comment: Damnit, apparently, I didn't set it up right in @ app, I added the function but forgot to use it. Now it seems to work fine with @app in every single blueprint. I thought the other blueprints weren't seeing it.

Comment: @Dexter Please consider updating your "accepted answer"!
(I found the one by *imwilsonxu* most useful)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Blueprint.before_request` is called before each request within the blueprint. If you want to call it before all blueprints, please use [before_app_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_request).

Comment: I believe this is the best answer.

Answer (score 19):

A little late here but:
This is what I do:
**Use the Blueprint variable to set the before request**

```
myblueprint = Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__, template_folder="templates")

def before_myblueprint():
    #code here

myblueprint.before_request(before_myblueprint)
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm even later here, but incrementing on Johnston's answer, you could use the same `before_request` decorator as well, for example:

```
bp_v1 = Blueprint('api_v1', __name__)

@bp_v1.before_request
def before_anything():
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you doing it good by trying initiate user in `before_request`, the problem is that `g` object has nothing before the request, so you need to deal with it differently. Get the user from cookies in `before_request` most probably and then later add it to session, from there maybe to `g`. I think it would be worth to take a look at or use Flask-login. Or just [read the code](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login.py) of it and maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: i been looking into that. But I don't understand why it's needed because I thought flask already created an automatic cookie to preserve session data.