# Python Flask: How to implement multiple URL redirects in bulk?

Tags: python, flask

I am aware of Flask's `redirect(<URL>)` function that I can use inside routes.

But I have dozens of URLs that I need to redirect to a different website. I was wondering if there is a way I can implement redirects without writing multiple `redirect(<URL>)` statements across many blueprints and routes.

I was wondering if I could just supply Flask with my redirect mapping data in bulk. e.g.

```
www.example.com/example-1 => subdomain.example.com/example-1
www.example.com/example-2 => subdomain.example.com/example-2
www.example.com/example-3 => subdomain.example.com/example-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cheesecake87` from Reddit provided this solution, which I will mark as accepted answer.

```
from flask import request

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    redir = (
        ('https://www.example.com/example-1', 'https://subdomain.example.com/example-1'), 
        ('https://www.example.com/example-2', 'https://subdomain.example.com/example-2')
    )
    for v in redir:
        if request.url in v[0]:
            return redirect(v[1], code=302)
```

Source 1: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/115sdhm/comment/j95q9va/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Source 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121323

`Hack-R`'s solution was good. But redirection URL rule was sorted to be at the very bottom of the URL rules list (by Werkzeug), so the redirection didn't take place unless I removed the original routes that I wanted redirected.

With this solution, URLs are evaluated BEFORE it reaches the URL rule list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do redirects with dictionaries or a list of tuples to hold them.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define a dictionary of redirect mappings
redirects = {
    "/example-1": "http://subdomain.example.com/example-1",
    "/example-2": "http://subdomain.example.com/example-2",
    "/example-3": "http://subdomain.example.com/example-3"
}

# Register a route to handle all the redirects
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def redirect_to_new_url(path):
    if path in redirects:
        new_url = redirects[path]
        return redirect(new_url, code=302)
    else:
        return "Page not found", 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```